# How to save location in a static variable(e.X, e.Y)

Tags: c#

I drawing objects with mouse up and mouse down methods, so I am getting their the location with e.X and e.Y. So how can I save the location of every drew item.

Comment: What do you mean by "save the location"? Set a variable? Write it to a file? Database?...

Comment: Set it to a static variable or an array, so when I draw a second object I can still have an access to the location (x and y integers) of the first object.

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can create private variables to track the start and end location, and then update them with values in the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events obtained from the `MouseEventArgs` argument. You can also create a `List<Rectangle>` to keep track of all the rectangles you've drawn, and add to it in the `MouseUp` event:

```
// Variables to keep track of the current drawing
private Point startLocation;
private Point endLocation;

// A list to hold all drawings
private List<Rectangle> drawnItems = new List<Rectangle>();

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Capture the start point
    startLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Capture the end point
    endLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

    // Save this rectangle in our list
    drawnItems.Add(new Rectangle(startLocation,
        new Size(endLocation.X - startLocation.X, endLocation.Y - startLocation.Y)));

    // Display a message
    var message = new StringBuilder();

    message.AppendLine("You drew a rectangle starting at point: " +
                    $"{startLocation} and ending at point: {endLocation}\n");

    message.AppendLine("Here are all the rectangles you've drawn:");

    for(int i = 0; i < drawnItems.Count; i++)
    {
        message.AppendLine($" {i + 1}. " + drawnItems[i]);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(message.ToString());
}
```

**Ouput**
...after drawing 4 rectangles:

[image]

Comment: But how can you save the start and end point after you have drew a second object?

Comment: In the same way, only use a `List<Rectangle>` (or something like that) to save them in. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: I think this is the best answer you'll get, it solves your problem and there isn't much more that can be contributed without knowing what your objective is. Also, SO is for technical help, not really software design. You may have some more studying to do on your own.

Comment: Great, how to show in in a proper format like yours and also how to retrieve the x and y values and store them in an integer.
https://imgur.com/a/IHaVj7I

Comment: I'm using the default `ToString` implementation of `Point` and `Rectangle` in my sample. It appears that the object you're using doesn't override `ToString`, so you'll have to create your own string based on the properties of the object that you want to display.